# No endpoint settings in azure console for ubuntu server

Tags: azure

i've trouble getting proper access to my servers services.

It's an "new" ubuntu vm so that i can't access it via the old "manage" portal.

I cannot change the endpoint settings for this vm because the entry "endpoints" is missing, what can i do to fix this? Or am i supposed to use iptables / ufw? Because that's doesn't seem to be the case since i can access my server via ssh and either iptables nor ufw have entries for ssh.

Thanks in advise for helping informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Resource Manager (ARM) is quite new addition to the Azure, so some things are only doable via Powershell at this time.

Please consider the following explanation on how to attach a Load Balancer to your Resource Group and then configure what we called "endpoints":

http://blog.itaysk.com/2015/08/03/azure-load-balancer-in-resource-manager-arm/

Comment: Yep good hint. I just installed the "old" ones and everything was fine.

Comment: Try and go back to the Azure Classic portal.  It make life alot easier.